# How to paste the text with the same property in Actionscript 3?

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I want to paste the text with the same height,width,color etc (i.e same as the time of copying the text).

I am using a textArea where i am adding text and also changing the color,font,size of the text by using style but if i am coping the text from textArea and pasting them then i am getting the text with default font style (Only changing heights are coming).

I have attached the image where you can see the difference

[image]

So anybody have an idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You may set the same `TextFormat` to both text inputs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a [TextFlow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html) and [TextConverter](http://help.adobe.com/es_ES/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html) with the methods export and importToFlow to use and TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT to get the format with the style attributes